# Pbcopy acts as Pbpaste when symlinked

Tags: clipboard, xclip

To keep my configs sane between environments, I thought it's a great idea to do the following on MacOS.

```
ln -s /usr/bin/pbcopy /usr/local/bin/xclip
```

However, my `xclip` symlink does not act just as `pbcopy`. Instead, for some reason, it acts as a `pbpaste`.

```
$ echo hello | /usr/bin/pbcopy

$ echo hello | /usr/bin/pbpaste
hello

$ echo hello | /usr/local/bin/xclip
hello
```

The third command was expected to behave like the first command, not like the second command.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This typically happens with programs that implement multiple behaviors and decide on which one to act by inspecting the name by which they were called.

This technique is used in some popular tools such as `busybox` which provides most of the typical Linux/Unix standard utilities in a single binary.

In this case, it seems the same binary is implementing both the "copy" and "paste" behavior and it is acting like "paste" by default (except when the called name matches `pbcopy` exacty.)

You can easily work around this, by making your `xclip` a shell script that calls `pbcopy` instead of a symlink. This would be roughly the equivalent to what you currently have:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec pbcopy "$@"
```

The `exec` ensures `pbcopy` will be run in the same process, will replace the shell, which will no longer be around during execution.

The `"$@"` will pass any arguments verbatim to `pbcopy` (older shells needed something like `${1+"$@"}` to handle no arguments correctly, but that is not the case with modern implementations of the shell.) This is the same that happens with arguments when using the symlink approach.

Don't forget to make the script executable:

```
$ chmod +x /usr/local/bin/xclip
```

I'm not sure whether the arguments expected by `xclip` really do match those interpreted by `pbcopy`, but my guess is that they shouldn't. If you want to translate the arguments typically taken by `xclip` into ones parsed by `pbcopy`, this script would also be an appropriate place to do that.